# SQL Big Query Full join tables in order to use same filter

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables in Google Big Query which I want to join in order to filter (with one filter) the data in a dashboard.

Table one contains Date, Country, and Revenues. Table two contains Date, Country, and Costs.
I want to be able to filter on Date and Country and show both Revenues and costs. However, there are days/countries with no Revenue but costs, and there are days with no Costs but Revenues.

I first connected the tables using a left join, which resulted in an incomplete table missing costs for days that do not have revenue for certain countries. Now I tried to resolve this by using a full join like this:

```
FULL JOIN (SELECT
date,
shipping_country AS shipping_country_spend,
sum(spend) AS Spend
FROM spend_total Group by 1,2) oo
ON oo.date = o.Date
WHERE shipping_country_spend IS NULL OR shipping_country_spend = shipping_country
```

However, I still do not get the costs in for date/country combinations that have no Revenue.

Secondly, for the costs, I have one remainder column called "other" - which is obviously not a country. I would like this to come in as a separate row, with country "other" and revenues = 0.

Important is, that I can use "date"  and "country"  as a filter. The desired outcome would be something like:

```
Date : Country : Revenue : Cost
15-05-2020 : Spain : 3000 : 200
15-05-2020 : Belgium : 0 : 300
15-05-2020 : Other : 0 : 500
15-05-2020 : Netherlands : 2000 : 0
```

Thanks much!

Comment: Could you share the complete query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `USING` clause solves your problem.  This looks like:

```
select date, country, r.revenue, s.spend
from (select date, revenue_country as country, sum(revenue) as revenue
      from revenue
      group by date, revenue_country
     ) r full join
     (select date, shipping_country as country, sum(spend) as spend
      from spend_total
      group by date, shipping_country
     ) s
     using (date, country)
where date = ? and country = ?;
```

The following are important with this approach:

- `date` and `country` need to have the same names in both queries.
- The `using` clause is needed.  The simpler syntax here works because of that clause.
- No table aliases are used to qualify `date` and `country`, in either the `select` or `where`.

You can also express this with an `on` clause, but it is much more complicated:

```
select coalesce(s.date, r.date) as date, 
       coalesce(r.county, s.country) as country,
       r.revenue, s.spend
from (select date, revenue_country as country, sum(revenue) as revenue
      from revenue
      group by date, revenue_country
     ) r full join
     (select date, shipping_country as country, sum(spend) as spend
      from spend_total
      group by date, shipping_country
     ) s
     using s.date = r.date and r.county = s.country
where coalesce(s.date, r.date) = ? and
      coalesce(r.county, s.country) = ?;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your reply. I tried both solutions but unfortunately I get the error message "Positional parameters are not supported". I am using Google Big Query. Do you have any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: The `?` is for whatever filters you want.  They are meant to be suggestive of filtering, which is part of your question.  You would put in whatever is appropriate for the filtering (it is not really relevant to the rest of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could you see if this is what you want?

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE t1
AS SELECT DATE '2020-1-1' Date, 'US' Country, 100 Revenues
  UNION ALL 
   SELECT DATE '2020-1-2' Date, 'MX' Country, 100 Revenues;

CREATE TEMP TABLE t2
AS SELECT DATE '2020-1-1' Date, 'US' Country, 200 Costs
  UNION ALL 
   SELECT DATE '2020-2-2' Date, 'MX' Country, 200 Costs;

SELECT COALESCE(t1.Date, t2.Date) Date,  COALESCE(t1.Country, t2.Country) Country, Revenues, Costs
FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 USING (Date, Country);
```

Output:

```
+------------+---------+----------+-------+
|    Date    | Country | Revenues | Costs |
+------------+---------+----------+-------+
| 2020-02-02 | MX      |     NULL |   200 |
| 2020-01-01 | US      |      100 |   200 |
| 2020-01-02 | MX      |      100 |  NULL |
+------------+---------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Hi Yun, Thanks for your reply. Do I change "from t2" in the query into from "spend_total" (my table)? Or where do I get my data in? Thanks!